# ng-repeat called from controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to write out list of some items in my app using ng-repeat but i faced with this problem:

**Template**

```
<ion-slide-box  on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" ng-controller="AccountCtrl" ng-init="getData()">
    <ion-slide   ng-repeat="statitem in stats">
        <div class="box vh80">
            <h1>{{statitem.name}}</h1>
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

**And in AccountCtrl**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
    .controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, Friends) {

        $scope.getData = function() {

            console.log('test');
            var friends = [
                { id: 0, name: 'Scruff McGruff' },
                { id: 1, name: 'G.I. Joe' },
                { id: 2, name: 'Miss Frizzle' },
                { id: 3, name: 'Ash efe' }
            ];
            $scope.stats = friends;
         }
   });
```

Problem is, that no item is obtained in template.

Where can be problem please?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

I solved it by moving the method calling to the parent div.

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="AccountCtrl" ng-init="getData()">
```

Answer (score 1):

try to clear the template a little bit to test to be sure that your HTML is 100% right, so you may make such this:

```
<div ng-controller="AccountCtrl" ng-init="getData()">
    <div ng-repeat="statitem in stats">
          <h1>{{statitem.name}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and if you see any results you have then you have to check your HTML and CSS template.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by moving the method calling to the parent div.

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="AccountCtrl" ng-init="getData()">
```